# How can i install and configure google map on E-commerce Website in Magento 2.4.5?

Tags: checkout, extensions, contact-us, magento2.4.5, google-map

I have freshly installed magento 2.4.5 on windows, I'm creating Pizza store, now I have to add google map for checkout process and to track the address, can anyone help me out? It will mean a lot to me.!

Answer (score 0):

To add Google Maps to the checkout process in Magento 2.4.5, you can follow these steps:

1. First, you need to get a Google Maps API key. You can do this by following the instructions on the Google Cloud Platform website.
2. Once you have the API key, log in to your Magento 2.4.5 admin panel and navigate to Stores > Configuration.
3. In the left-hand menu, click on Sales > Shipping Settings.
4. Under the Google Maps section, enter your API key in the API Key field.
5. Configure the remaining settings as per your requirement.
6. Save the configuration and clear the cache.

That's it! Google Maps should now be added to your checkout process in Magento 2.4.5.

Note: If you are using a local environment like XAMPP or WAMP, you may encounter an issue with Google Maps not loading due to the local environment's IP address not being whitelisted in the Google API Console. In this case, you can try adding the IP address to the whitelist or testing on a live server.

There is another tool that helps you to make localhost on HTTPS, if you really want to work on localhost then let me know I will tell you here how you can configure localhost on HTTPS then you can test all the stuff on localhost.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.